# calculate avg return "0" PHP

Tags: php, json

I have MySQL with Float Values which are pressure parametters. I need to calculate average. But the code I make returns me average "empty" in my json response.

Here is the json response I get:

```
{"result":{"pressure":{"min":[{"Id":"2","presion":"0","Insertado":"2016-08-16 16:20:08"},{"Id":"5","presion":"0","Insertado":"2016-08-16 18:09:04"}],"max":[{"Id":"3","presion":"55","Insertado":"2016-08-16 16:22:14"}],"avg":[]},"last_entry":{"Id":"8","presion":"50","Insertado":"2016-08-16 18:28:45"}}}
```

As it shows. avg give empty!.

This is code in PHP

```
$press_values = get_press_values($json_object->result);

    // get pressure result set with respected values
    $press_result = get_press_result_set_from_values($json_object->result,$press_values);

    // get latest entry
    $latest_entry = get_latest_date_entry($json_object->result);

    // Wrap results in an array
    $output_result = array(
        'pressure' => $press_result,
        'last_entry' => $latest_entry
    );
}
```

Then.

```
function get_press_values($result){

$min = -1;
$max = -1;
$avg = -1;

// get all pressure values
$pressures = array_map(function($result_item) {
  return intval($result_item->presion);
}, $result);

if($pressures){
    $min = min($pressures);
    $max = max($pressures);
    $avg = intval(calculate_average($pressures));
}

return array(
    'min' => $min,
    'max' => $max,
    'avg' => $avg
);
```

}

Then:

```
function get_press_result_set_from_values($array,$value){
$min_objs = array();
$max_objs = array();
$avg_objs = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {

    if($item->presion == $value['min']){
        $min_objs[] = $item;
    }

    if($item->presion == $value['max']){
        $max_objs[] = $item;
    }

    if($item->presion == $value['avg']){
        $avg_objs[] = $item;
    }
}

return array(
    'min' => $min_objs,
    'max' => $max_objs,
    'avg' => $avg_objs,
);
```

}
then:

```
function calculate_average($arr) {
$total = 0;
$count = count($arr); //total numbers in array
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $total = $total + $value; // total value of array numbers
}
$average = ($total/$count); // get average value
return $average;
```

}

Comment: The amount of code in this question clearly shows a lack of basic debugging. Step through your code yourself and find the problem or at the very least isolate the problem part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in your code:

```
if($item->presion == $value['avg']){
    $avg_objs[] = $item;
}
```

will only add an item if the `presion` perfectly matches the average, which can be very unlikely, depending on your data of course.

**update**: For example you have the values 50, 51, 54, 55. The average is 53. Your code will not find any `$item->presion` which is equal to 53, because the average doesn't need an item that has that value (in contrast to min and max).

You should check if you actually mean the median (which has to be determined in a different way ...).

**update2**: to get the average into your result, you have to change 
`$avg_objs = array();` to `$avg_objs = $value['avg'];`. and remove the part from your code that I posted above.

Also, if you want your average to not be an integer, you should change the line

```
$average = ($total/$count);
```

to

```
$average = (float)$total / $count;
```

and remove the `intval` from:

```
$avg = intval(calculate_average($pressures));
```

Comment: Hi Jakumi- I need the average. One parameter which is the result of Average of all parameters. I am not sure, but maybe the problem is the "intval" which is giving back "0". I am no sure...

Comment: @OscarC. well you could find out by printing the average and intval of the average. But what I noted was, that it's unlikely you'll find an average in your data (depending on your data, updated the post)

Comment: Hi Jakumi. Need the to get "53" value, how do you would do...?

Comment: @OscarC. change `$avg_objs = array();` to `$avg_objs = $value['avg'];` and remove the part with `$item->presion == $value['avg']`

Comment: Now give me value but not acorrect, I have 11,11,10,51 and give me 37.-  take out this** //if($item->presion == $value['avg']){
  // $avg_objs[] = $item;*** and then  *** make this $avg_objs = $value['avg'];

Comment: You probably have more/other values, because this just doesn't fit with your code at all. At some point, you should probably append an update to your question where  you post your new code and describe what goes wrong. And I think now would be a good time.

Comment: Hi Jakumi. The code solution is correct 100%. Sorry was my mistake, I was making a trial with a table which was receiving data from a sensor and I forgot to turnit off, so It received data that change the result meanwhile we were here. Tks.